# Problema al ejecutar Selenium con Python

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.7, selenium-webdriver

Trato de ejecutar Selenium en Python pero no me reconoce el driver. Cuando le doy CTRL+B me sale de inmediato `[Finished in 1.3s]` y no abre el navegador. La ruta es exactamente donde está el driver.

Código:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\driver_chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
driver.close()
```

Resultado:

```
[Finished in 1.3s]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posibilidad puede ser que el navegador se esté cerrando tan pronto se está abriendo porque no tiene ninguna instrucción para detener la ejecución.

Por otro lado, verifica que la versión de driver corresponda con la versión de Chrome que tiene instalado el equipo. Entonces:

1- Descargar Selenium de la fuente confiable:

```
pip install selenium
```

2- [Descargar Chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) correspondiente. No descargar uno mayor porque a lo mejor no está estable o no funciona bien con la versión anterior de navegador.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"la_ruta_absoluta_del_chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Con ese código, la página debe desplegarse por 5 segundos y luego cerrarse.

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, esa fue la solución te agradezco mucho

Answer (score 0):

A mí me pasaba algo similar y agregando las últimas 3 líneas de la respuesta también funcionó mi código.

Aquí dejo igual el ejemplo con el que estoy trabajando:

```
# Librerías
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import pandas as pd

driver_path = 'ruta a donde está\\chromedriver.exe'

service = Service(executable_path=driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.inegi.org.mx/")
time.sleep(20)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

En este caso se queda la página abierta por 20 segundos :)